# CSP refuses to load GAPI even in Offscreen Document

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, google-api-js-client

I am trying to build a *Chrome extension* that writes in a *Google Document* using a*GAPI object*. I am getting 4 similar errors because CSP blocks them

> Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I've tried creating an *Offscreen Document* in my *service-worker* like this:

```
async function createOffscreen() {
    if (await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()) return;
    console.log('hi');
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
        url: 'foreground.html',
        reasons: ['USER_MEDIA'],
        justification: 'testing',
    });
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (
        changeInfo.status == 'complete' &&
        tab.status == 'complete' &&
        tab.url != undefined
    ) {
        if (tab.url.includes('https://docs.google.com/document')) {
            await createOffscreen();
            const queryParameters = tab.url.substr(35, 44); // gets current docs
            await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                type: 'NEW',
                videoId: queryParameters,
            });
        }
    }
});
```

yet I get the same erros.

Comment: What makes you think offscreen doesn't cause that error?

Comment: Well, someone answered me a similar question: `The only way to use gapi object in ManifestV3 is to do it inside a sandboxed frame inside your popup or chrome.offscreen document` . The same problem is solved in Manifest V2 with background pages, but: `To replace functionality in the transition from background pages to extension service workers, developers can use the chrome.offscreen API`